# Using Session variable as WHERE predicate; am I approaching it wrongly?

Tags: php, session-variables

We would like to query our database and sample records based on a particular user's department.

Given the app design, the only way I know to do this is to filter the query by using dept's session variable.

The code below is not working.

Data gets returned if I comment out the session variable.

Nothing is getting retrieved with the session variable as filter.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Is the session variable route the wrong approach?

Thanks in advance for help.

```
//Start your session
session_start();

// Connect to SQL Server database
include("../sqlConnect.php");

// Construct query
$loginName = $_GET['loginName'];


//Ok, let's grab user's dept from query

$sql = "SELECT ISNULL(dept,'NA') AS 'dept' FROM emp where ([userName]) = lower('$userName')"
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$results = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($results,$row);
    $dept = $row['dept'];
}

//Store department in the session
$_SESSION['dept'] = $dept;

//Now extract records based on dept

$tsql ="SELECT 
     r.REQUESTID,
     convert(char(10),r.[currDate],101),
     r.[startedDBY],
     e.[dept],
     e.[WORKPHONE],
     e.[EMAIL],
     r.[DESCRIPTION],
     r.[DETAILS],
     r.[PROBLOCATION],
     c.[COMMENTS]'     
FROM EMPLOYEE e,REQUEST r,CUSTOMERCALL c 
WHERE LOGINNAME='$loginName' 
AND c.REQUESTID=r.requestid 
AND e.dept = '" . $_SESSION['dept'] . "'
";


$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);
if( $stmt === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$results = array();

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($results,$row);
}

 echo json_encode($results);


// Free connection resources
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
sqlsrv_close( $conn);
```

Comment: Did you verify that variable contains the value you expect? Does the query work outside of your code?

Comment: why are you using a session in the first place if you're defining the variable and the query in the same script?

Comment: before the line $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql); add the line: die($tsql); and update your question to show us the output.

Comment: @halabuda, et al, WOW, I get nothing when I put thedie($tsql); exactly where you wanted it. I know for sure dept values are not null.

John, it works only if I remove the session variable I am using as WhERE clause.

Comment: you get NOTHING at all? not even the rest of the query? or nothing where the dept value should be?

Comment: @halabuda, yes the page is blank, not even the rest of the query.